# Не выводится "Hello, World!"

Tags: perl

Perl тупит или я. Создаю файл. пишу туда:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Hello, world!\n";
```

Результат:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Hello, world!\n";
```

Вместо "Hello, world!".

Comment: а каким образом это вы такой результат получаете? через браузер? выполняя файл?

Comment: файл на сервере. через браузер

Comment: а с чего вы решили, что браузер будет выполнять perl'овый код? а сервер знает о том, что этот код нужно выполнять? у апача (или какой у вас сервер) прописано, что ему делать с такими файлами?

Comment: на сервере ведь есть интерпретатор perl. а на вопрос:
-а сервер знает о том, что этот код нужно выполнять? у апача (или какой у вас сервер) прописано, что ему делать с такими файлами?
Ответить не могу , ибо нуб пока :-D

Comment: ну то что он там есть дает вам лишь возможность запустить (зайдя на сервер по ssh к примеру) ваш скрипт с помощью команды

perl script.pl

Comment: Положите этот файл на сервере в /cgi-bin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Апач? Создайте в каталоге со скриптами файл .htaccess, прописав в нем разрешение запускать сценарии через CGI-интерфейс:

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .pl
```

Answer (score 1):

И почемуто все вдруг забыли о такой мелочи, как:
    `print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";`